# Impact of Azure databricks and ADF deployment to running jobs/pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

For Azure DevOps to deploy azure databricks, if there is running jobs on databricks (for example it is a streaming job), would the current running job still be running or be stopped? And will it still use the old lib or new? When will the new code be picked up?

Similar for ADF deployment, how would deployment impact running pipelines?

Comment: please add more details - do you use "existing cluster" vs "new cluster", etc.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any issue and conflict between pipelines if you have configured them correctly keeping all the parameters like, cluster size, pipeline schedules, Azure Integration Runtime  (in ADF), etc. as per the requirement.

**Key points to remember while configuring Azure DevOps pipeline to run Databricks Notebook:**

- **Cluster management:** While creating a DevOps pipeline, make sure the Databricks Notebooks you will be running must have sufficient cluster resources to run (RAM and vCores). If you are running each Notebook in different cluster then it's sorted. But if multiple Notebooks sharing same cluster, you need to take care that all the Notebooks must get required resources to run the Job.
- **Pipeline schedule:** Azure Pipelines provides several types of triggers to configure how your pipeline starts.

  > Scheduled triggers start your pipeline based on a schedule, such as a
  > nightly build.

  > Event-based triggers start your pipeline in response to events, such
  > as creating a pull request or pushing to a branch.

Based on the above schedule types, you can manage your pipelines.

The pipeline can pick new libraries if you use event-based trigger, i.e., run the pipeline after making changes in the DevOps Repos.

**Key points to remember while configuring Azure Data Factory pipeline to run Databricks Notebook:**

- Cluster management is same as mentioned above for Azure DevOps
- Make sure Azure Integration Runtime (IR) which provides compute environment to run pipeline has sufficient resources to manage multiple parallel pipeline runs.

If you keep other mentioned points in mind while configuring your Azure Databricks, ADF and Azure DevOps, I hope everything runs well.